# How do I counter Abaddon late game?

Tags: dota-2

His ult, "Borrowed Time", seems unbelievably powerful.  I've seen an allied Abaddon charge into the enemy fountain on purpose, to heal (while killing stuff, of course).

Recently, Abaddon was single-handedly wrecking my entire team, late game, despite my teammates in lane against him killing him several times in the early game.

How do I stop Abaddon?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's take a look at what you can do :

- Best solution : get a Eul's scepter ! As soon as Borrowed Time is triggered, Eul's him and he wont be able to regenerate thus using his ult for nothing. Many Abaddon will go in the melee thinking they are "unkillable", this will make them think twice before doing it again. You can obtain the same result with Astral emprisonment (Outworld Devourer), Disruption (Shadow Demon), Nightmare (Bane), Song of the Siren (Naga), tornado (Invoker) and Wind brewling's Cyclone (Brewmaster)
- Axe's Culing blade overpass Borrowed time. Borrowed Time triggers at 400 or less HP while Aganim's scepter and Culling blade at level 11 insta-kill a target below 450HP (small margin) and 625HP at level 16 (better margin). Give that Abaddon some taste of Axe's axe
- Abaddon is reliant on mana to cast Apotic shield : diffusal blade on your carry or any mana burning spell will help you.
- Abaddon as a melee carry doesn't have a great disable (Such as Void or Alchemist) or a great chasing potential (such as Magina, Phantom Lancer or Mortred) so slowing him and kiting him in a teamfight is really easy. Get a support with a powerfull slow (Tuskar, Venomancer, Crystal Maiden etc.) or do it with an item (Rod of Atos, Skadi). Abaddon is not that great of a damage dealer,if he uses a bkb to prevent slow : just kite him or back a little then fight once he's no longer magic immune.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the items to counter Abbadon which is just interfering with your own gameplay (if you don't play an intelligence based character), I would suggest to counter-pick Abbadon in the picking phase.

Every character with high stunning potential is suitable here, but you should choose a character that doesn't lack mana in the early game, to counter his shield spam.

Here are some possibilities: Axe, Lich, Lion, Windrunner, Lina etc.

The rest is just teamplay just as it is in a teambased game.